# How to kill child processes when killing from pid file

Tags: macos, bash, shell, scripting

```
kill -9 `cat ~/code/posbox/posbox.pid`
```

I'm running the command above to kill a process. The pid is in the file, it's correctly killing the process but child processes are still running

when I do

```
kill <PID number>
```

it kills the process along with all the child processes. How do I kill all parent and child processes from a pid given in a pid file?

Comment: did you try `man kill`?

Comment: @KevinDTimm `help kill` would be more relevant for the bash builtin `:)`

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf - you kids and your newfangled toys ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since `kill <PID number>` works, just use that:

```
# By default, send SIGTERM, not SIGKILL (9)
kill $(cat ~/code/posbox/posbox.pid)
```

It sounds like your process catches the TERM signal and passes it on to its children before exiting, allowing them all to exit cleanly. Using `kill -9` ends the parent *immediately*, without giving it a chance to tell its children to exit at all.